# Call a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have to make a demo using "delibratelydangerousSnippet" for rendering html in JavaScript, I have done it, now I want to call a function onclick of a div.

I have tried this but nothing is happening. No error, no event happening, can anybody please tell me what is the problem in this code?

```
  mainString = '<ons-list-item  onclick="call()">'+
                                '<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">' +
                                '<ons-row class="detail-row row ons-row-inner">' +
                                '<ons-col width="30px" style="flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px; -moz-box-flex: 0;" class="col ons-col-inner">' +
                                '<ons-icon fixed-width="true" icon="ion-android-call" class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-home fa-lg"></ons-icon>' +
                                '</ons-col>' +
                                '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" >' +
                                '<div class="desc">'+"Phone Number: "+data['Details'][i]['varPhone'] + '</div>' +
                                '</ons-col> ' +
                                '</ons-row>' +
                                '</ons-list-item>';
```

In the same JavaScript I have defined my `call()` function as below:

```
 function call(){
     window.location.href = 'tel:+1' + phone;
 }
```

Comment: Are you actually doing anything with `mainString`?  If you're just populating it then it won't show in the page.

Comment: You have an onclick inside an end-tag?? You said you wanted the onclick in a <div>.  Is <ons-list-item> an Angular directive?

Comment: yes ,sorry for that,but now it give me `ReferenceError: call is not defined` error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an onclick inside an ending tag: an ending tag just ends the tag, but you cannot click on it. In other words the onclick can only be in starting tags.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByTag("ons-list-item")[0].onclick = call;
}
```

Or give your ons-list-item an ID, like 'olitem' (just example) and use:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("olitem").onclick = call;
}
```

Comment: yes ,sorry for that,but now it give me `ReferenceError: call is not defined error`.

Comment: Try putting the function above the function with the assignment, or better: put all code that uses functions in document ready (JQuery) or window.onload (basic JS) so it makes sure all functions are defined.

Comment: Well i am newbie and i am not getting it.:(

Comment: Can you put your JS as a jsfiddle, so I can take a look at it?

Comment: just i want is to make a phonecall on click of this html component.now can anyone pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the onClick event in HTML page, try to provide the "id" to the element in the JS string.

```
mainString = '</ons-list-item  id="myId">'+`enter code here`
                                '<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">' +
                                '<ons-row class="detail-row row ons-row-inner">' +
                                '<ons-col width="30px" style="flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px; -moz-box-flex: 0;" class="col ons-col-inner">' +
                                '<ons-icon fixed-width="true" icon="ion-android-call" class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-home fa-lg"></ons-icon>' +
                                '</ons-col>' +
                                '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" >' +
                                '<div class="desc">'+"Phone Number: "+data['Details'][i]['varPhone'] + '</div>' +
                                '</ons-col> ' +
                                '</ons-row>' +
                                '</ons-list-item>';

Once the HTML gets loaded try to access the HTML element using jQuery and hook up the click event on the same element using id.

$("#myId").on("click",function(){
 window.location.href = 'tel:+1' + phone;
});
```